# How to UPDATE a table based on the matches of multi-column indexes of different tables

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, database-indexes

I hope I'm not asking something really stupid, I did search if a question like this had been answered before and didn't find anything conclusive.

These are the statements that created the two tables in question:

```sql
CREATE TABLE race (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, --raceId
    year INT,
    round INT,
    circuit_id INT REFERENCES circuit (id) 
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    name CITEXT,
    date DATE,
    time TIME,
    url CITEXT
)
;

ALTER TABLE race ADD COLUMN season_last_round BOOL;
UPDATE race SET season_last_round = False;

CREATE TABLE 
season_last_round AS 
    SELECT  
        year, 
        max(round) AS last_round
    FROM race
    GROUP BY year
    ORDER BY year
    ;
```

So what I really want to achieve is to have the `season_last_round` be `True` if it's actually the `max(round)` on that `year`.

My approach was then to create multi-column indexes on both tables

```sql
CREATE INDEX season_lr_year_last_round ON season_last_round (year, last_round);

CREATE INDEX race_year_round ON race (year, round);
```

And do something like....

```sql
UPDATE race
SET season_last_round = True
WHERE 
season_lr_year_last_round = race_year_round ;
```

But that obviously does not work.

I'd really appreciate your help and insights guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub-query to get that information:

```
UPDATE race
  SET season_last_round = true
FROM (
  SELECT year, max(round) AS last_round
  FROM race
  GROUP BY year
) t 
WHERE t.year = race.year
  and t.last_round = race.round;
```

Another option is a sub-query using IN:

```
UPDATE race
  SET season_last_round = true
WHERE (year, round) IN (SELECT year, max(round) AS last_round
                        FROM race
                        GROUP BY year)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! worked like a charm! Second option is neat because there's no reason for the `season_last_round` table to exist, therefore I just dropped it. The cleaner the schema the better.

Comment: @Luis: the first one doesn't create a table either